# Build admin with UI instead of react

Tags: web-apps, web-development

I am looking for a tool that would allow me to build professional admin interfaces assuming I already have APIs (REST and/or GraphQL).

I tried [retool](https://retool.com/) but I would like to have more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Give https://superset.apache.org/ a look.
Its made by Apache, and has all kinds of graph and datasets to explore.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about superset. I am however more looking for user journeys, ie list of customers, click on customer see customer detail and maybe the list of orders linked with this customer